# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am beginner in Spring,
I get the following error while setting up the spring mvc. Please help me to solve this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLo      ader.java:3107)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.jav     a:1348)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1828)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:3107)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1348)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1828)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:3107)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1348)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1828)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Proce
```

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: No, i am simple adding the jar file

Comment: i also add the spring core 3.1.4 jar and spring orm , spring web mvc jar

Answer (score -1):

Try using maven to load your jar files  and before running your application go to properties -> Deployment Assembly and make sure your jars( either you added them or by maven) are there

Comment: you have any idea using without maven ?

Comment: put your jar files under  WebContent/libs and include this path in the Deployment Assembly